# How to add depth / thickness to edges evenly

Tags: modeling, vertices, edges

Hi is there an easy way to add thickness to a bunch of vertices and edges and do it evenly?

I have this mesh with no faces and I want to thicken it to an even thickness.

[image: edges and vertices needing to be converted]

I have followed another example where I should convert the mesh to a curve and then tweak the bevel settings in the object data panel and this is what I get which is pretty close to what I want but as you can see the thickness is uneven whereas I want it all to be the same thickness:

[image: Mesh converted to curve and bevel added]

I have also tried a wireframe modifier on a mesh with faces but this yields even worse results as the frame is still uneven but also it adds edges where I don't want them and the wireframe is not cylindrical.

Is there a better way to do this?

Thanks

Comment: It might be helpful to people trying to help you if you uploaded an example blend file to the site https://blend-exchange.com and add that link in the question.

Comment: Maybe try the Skin modifier but you may not like the generated topology

Comment: 2 possible reasons for uneven thickness. 1: your object may be carrying a non-uniform Scale transform (Ctrl-A, apply scale). 2. 3D Curves don't mitre corners evenly. If your object is intended to be flat, try constructing as a 2D curve (in its Shape settings), before rotating.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried it with geometry nodes?  You could create the lines then just use geometry nodes to make the round piping.

[image: img]

[image: img2]

Comment: Thanks for your detailed answer. I've followed the top example but unfortunately it didn't work. I just end up with a small ball in the middle of the mesh.

Comment: Interesting..this is where posting the file in the original question would help, something else maybe happening behind the scenes.

Comment: It works! I played about with the measurements in Circle Curve and Grid nodes and started to get something.This helped me to understand your second example and it works! Is there a way to cap the ends? They are hollow as there are no outer edges to the geometry unlike your plane and torus examples. Or should I just apply the modifier and do it manually?

Comment: @cannon303 Glad to hear it.  In the `Curve to Mesh` node there's a check box that is marked `Fill Caps` check that box and see if it fixes that issue.

Comment: Great thanks very much.